# Once again, obsolete comments not deleted- why this time?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/how-to-create-a-champion-advocating-change-in-a-loose-organisation) I once more assisted with clarification with the OP and in this case I asked questions in the comments, the OP answered and I asked them to edit their answers into the question. They did not do this, so I did.

Then I flagged their comment for deletion, with a note explaining why it should be deleted, and that request was declined. Why? The information now exists inside the question as well as in the OPs comment. The comment should be deleted.

I draw your attention to the accepted answer on [this meta question](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/753/why-were-my-obsolete-comment-flags-declined) where I have queried this kind of thing in the past.

Secondly I requested deletion for the OP's comment thanking me in the comment thread, for editing their question. That too was declined.

This is making me slightly angry- I am following procedure, the comments ARE obsolete, I am curating the site for the good of the readers and, in this case at least, what I have requested is not controversial.

Who is declining this kind of thing?

Comment: Some flags are handled by the community. However, I'm pretty sure comment deletion flags are only handled by the diamond moderators.